# Using audio and mic from device used to answer phone

Tags: bluetooth, calls, headset

I have 2 bluetooth devices:

  1. Wristband - which can also act as an earpiece

  2. Bluetooth earphones with a mic.

My wristband is always connected via bluetooth to my device, and my ear phones are only connected when i use them.

When someone phones me, doesn't matter with what i answer, there is a single device which is selected as the audio/mic device.

I know I can set a specific device to act as the one used when taking calls.

But, I want the device i use to answer to be the one i click when the phone rings, i.e.:

  1. If I click on the phone - the phone is used

  2. If I click on my wristband, then that is used

  3. If I click on .... you get the picture

I think this is a logical request.

Searched the web, failed to find a solution.